# Using Ninject in an Azure WebJobs but can't pass my db client

Tags: azure, ninject, azure-webjobssdk

I'm using Ninject in a new Azure WebJobs project. One of my repositories requires a Db client to be passed. How do I pass this client?

My bindings class is:

```
public class NinjectBindings : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
   public override void Load()
   {
       Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>();
   }
}
```

My Main function in the console app looks like this:

```
static void Main()
{
   var kernel = new StandardKernel();
   kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

   var config = new Configuration();
   config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

   DbClient _dbClient = new DbClient(config);

   IMyRepository myRepository = kernel.Get<IMyRepository>(); // This is where I get an error
}
```

My repository code is like this which is expecting the DbClient

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
   private DbClient _client;
   public MyRepository(DbClient client)
   {
      _client = client;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a binding for your DbClient.

I'd suggest being cautious around when components are released. I've not seen a good ninject example for web jobs yet so I've wired up manually. But that's just my thoughts...

Comment: I'm not clear. What do I bind my DbClient to? I don't have an interface for it.

Comment: You can bind it to itself: Bind<DbClient>().To<DbClient>();